# Changing index of a double summation

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, analysis, elementary-number-theory, summation

How does one prove the following result, where $x$ is a three-parameter function defined on $\mathbb Z^3$? $$ \sum_{\ell=1}^{P}\sum^{\ell-1}_{i=0}  x(\ell,i,\ell-i) \quad = \quad \sum^{P}_{j=1}\sum^{P-j}_{i=0} x(i+j,i,j)$$

I got as far as realising that they coincide when $x$ is constant. Note [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484373/changing-index-of-a-summation) is not quite the same.

Also, I noticed that:

The regions $\{0\leq i \leq \ell -1 \leq p -1, \ell>1\}$ and $\{0\leq j-1 \leq i+j -1 \leq p-1\}$, both in $\mathbb Z^2$, describe isosceles triangles (respectively, bottom-left triangle and bottom-right triangle of square with sides $\overline{(1,1)(1,p)}$ and $\overline{(1,1)(p-1,1)}\\$).

Comment: Regardless of how small a difference there is in your questions, you should still provide your work for what you have done so far my friend :-).

Comment: @TaylorRendon, I have done it, I'd appreciate you deleting your comment now please

Comment: Given that in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484373) you were asking to prove something that wasn't actually true, what's different about this one (e.g. are you more convinced in this case that the result is actually true, and if so why)?

Comment: See p.286 "Differential Eq. Driven by Rough Signals", Lyons, Rev. Mat. Iberoamericana, 1998. This is a well-cited paper that uses this result